# jQuery - To perform a search using submit button on a live search plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I started using `mark.js` live search plugin, and I was able to modify it to automatically scroll to the text part that's being searched on the page.

**Like this:**

```
SEARCH BOX |_jklmno____| <-- User searches here
    123
    456
    789
    abcde
    fghi
    jklmno <--- Then the page will automatically scroll and stop here.
    pqrst
```

-> Done, it found the text <-

The code works, how can I build a button that when submitted, the page will jump to the next result?

**I tried using this to jump to the next result when the form is submitted:**

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: mark.eq(index).offset().top}, 500);
    }
```

**This too:**

```
 else if ('mark[data-markjs]').live("submit", function(e) {
      e.mark();
              $('html,body').animate(
              {scrollTop: mark.offset().top -100}
              , 200);  

    });
```

**But it didn't work.**

**Here's the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krqzjxzc/15/) **(In order to see the search field, you have to scroll the result tab a little bit)**

**And here's the jQuery:**

```
$.noConflict()
jQuery(function($) {
  var mark = function() {

    // Read the keyword
     var keyword = $("input[name='keyword']").val();

    // Determine selected options
    var options = {


     "filter": function(node, term, counter, totalCounter){
        if(term === keyword && counter >= 1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    done: function() {
        var mark = $('mark[data-markjs]');
        if (mark.length) {

  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: mark.eq(index).offset().top}, 500);


        }       


/*
else if ('mark[data-markjs]').live("submit", function(e) {
  e.mark();
          $('html,body').animate(
          {scrollTop: mark.offset().top -100}
          , 200);  

});
*/



}






    };
    $("input[name='opt[]']").each(function() {
      options[$(this).val()] = $(this).is(":checked");  });




    // Mark the keyword inside the context
    $(".context").unmark();
    $(".context").mark(keyword, options);


 };

  $("input[name='keyword']").on("keyup", mark);
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", mark);



  $("input[name='keyword']").on("submit", mark);



 });
```

Comment: So there is no solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a while with your fiddle.
It's a cool problem.

I decided to use the up/down arrows to scroll to the prev/next result...
Instead of the enter key or a button.

Here is the main part that I changed:

```
$("input[name='keyword']").on("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.which==40){    // 40 = down arrow
        e.preventDefault();
        arrowOffset++;
    }
    if(e.which==38){    // 38 = up arrow
        e.preventDefault();
        arrowOffset--;
        if(arrowOffset<1){
            arrowOffset=1;
        }
    }
    mark(arrowOffset);
});
```

I did not found how to "un-highlight" the previous result...
But since arrows make it scroll to the right result, I think it is quite cool like this.

```
done: function() {
    var mark = $('mark[data-markjs]').last();   // Scroll to last <mark>
    if (mark.length) {  
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: mark.offset().top-90}, 500);
    }
}
```

Have a look at [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/xb0ck399/) for the complete updated script.

Comment: Seriously, I've never seen something more awesome than what you did this script, so far. I was expecting a enter button and you came with arrows and highlight. Thx a lot! It's been 1 week since I started working on this. Now I have a basis to create the buttons! YAY!

Comment: I just had fun with it! It is cool stuff you're doing. Please accept the answer (green check mark) ;)